# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio version 2.1.1 and when i try to generate signed apk file I got the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':_4SaleApp:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Volumes/Data/Work/4Sale_Android/4SaleApp_Studio/_4SaleApp/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/release/folders/1000/1f/main/classes.dex (No such file or directory)

can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue fixed when I restart android studio, and clean my project and build it, and generate signed apk.